# Django Celery - Missing something but I have no idea what? Have results but can't get them

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

My task goes into celery and gets results.  I know this because I can do this.

```
>>> ts = TaskState.objects.all()[0]
>>> ts
Out[31]: <TaskState: SUCCESS apps.checklist.tasks.bulk_checklist_process(ec01461b-3431-478d-adfc-6d6cf162e9ad) ts:2012-07-20 14:35:41>
>>> ts.state
Out[32]: u'SUCCESS'
>>> ts.result
Out[33]: u'{\'info\': ["Great",]}'
```

But when I attempt to use the [documented](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-task-if-i-have-the-id-that-points-there) way to get the result - all hell breaks loose..

```
>>> from celery.result import BaseAsyncResult
>>> result = BaseAsyncResult(ts.task_id)
>>> result.get()
../lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py:178: TxIsolationWarning: Polling results with transaction isolation level repeatable-read within the same transaction may give outdated results. Be sure to commit the transaction for each poll iteration.
  "Polling results with transaction isolation level "
```

So I have two questions.

1. What am I missing in my setup of celery that is causing this error.  I clearly have the results but BaseAsyncResult is jacked up.  I don't even know where to look for this?
2. Ignoring 1 for a sec it looks like as long as I have `ts.state == SUCCESS` I can just run with the `ts.result`.  What would be the drawback to that and what format is that result in?

**Update**

So the second part is easy.  *Scary* but easy..

```
context['results'] = resulting_values = result.get(propagate=False)
if not isinstance(resulting_values, dict):
    context['results'] = resulting_values = eval(context['task'].result)
    log.error("We should not be here..")
```

Answer (score 0):

It says so right in the warning you pasted:

```
TxIsolationWarning: Polling results with transaction isolation level repeatable-read 
within the same transaction may give outdated results. Be sure to commit the transaction   
for each poll iteration.
```

To use the database for results, and if you want to poll for them in the same process
then you either need to configure the isolation level of the database to be `READ-COMMITTED`
or commit the transaction before you check for the result.

Also `BaseAsyncResult` is deprecated, please use

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
```